# Java light weight and free dependency lister/analizer/diagram generator?

Tags: java, code-analysis, diagram, dependencies

I can't use IntelijIdea (it is too heavy here).

I have tried some others that are Eclipse plugins or external application but some didnt work, or the usage and shown results were quite confusing or even incomplete!

It could even be a textual output list/tree, nothing overly fancy, just something we could further parse/filter to determine if our project has good low coupling...

Something simple like this output would suffice:

```
A depends on B, C and D  
B depends on E and F  
F depends on A (warning: coupling problem!)
```

The coupling detection warn isnt even that necessary as we can filter it later.

Also, considering classes are loaded on demand, therefore we would have to run some kind of JUnit that tests all application flows, it would surely not be a problem at all.

Related to this question, is this one looking for ways to implement it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242123/how-to-implement-a-java-light-weight-dependency-analizer-that-generates-a-simple

Comment: It seems StarUML can reverse engineer using an extension (still have to test it). I couldnt find yet a way to do that using WhiteStarUML tho. and this question is highly related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34865/20687

Answer (score 1):

I found that a combination of [DeGraph](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/34902/20687) + [yEd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293175/1422630) will work.

at yEd: it seems a bit buggy as it will not show some things when we click on them, other times will show after a few retries. The main tip is to "focus node", at "neighborhood" or "predecessors" right click and "convert to document", that will let us zoom in to further analyze.